# DNS service outside hosting provider

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server, cloud-computing

I came to the conclusion that the DNS service at my hosting company is totally unreliable. But I don't want to change providers, because all their other services are great. In fact, it's a cloud server.

There are companys that offer DNS services. [DNS Made Easy](http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com/), [UltraDNS](http://www.ultradns.com/) or [Postpart](http://www.postpart.com/), just to name a few.

Why is Postpart giving it for free, DNSMadeEasy for $15/year and UltraDNS for $18/month? What's the real difference between these services?

thanks, cheers

Comment: "it's a cloud server, so there's not really much other options" -- huh?

Comment: if you're not looking for a heavier investment in reliability, it doesn't take much of a machine to run DNS on...I inherited a 486 that was serving a couple million DNS requests/day when I took over the networking support. It was so old the boot sector on the drive was trashed and had to be booted from floppy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely to be reliability, you get what you pay for. I suggest you look at the reviews of each service and then make your decision. At least with Postpart you can try it, and if it does not work out, simply cut your losses.

Comment: thanks, if it's only reliability, can I host the DNS on my testing server? My testing server hosting provider DNS works pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the real difference between these services?

It's often said that what customers want is a service that's:

1. fast
2. reliable
3. cheap

but that it's only ever possible to deliver two of those requirements.  Pick the two that matter to you.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, DNS Made Easy and UltraDNS both offer IP Anycast DNS (name servers are available at networks at different facilities). Both offer the same service, but UltraDNS will end up charging you a lot more. Not sure where you received your quote from, but $18 per month is remarkably cheap for them. Our company utilizes DNS Made Easy's corporate membership and have had zero issues and fast response time from Europe and the US for the past several years. They also have a 100% uptime claim with a 500% SLA. Seems like a no brainer to me.

Comment: here's the quote for UltraDNS https://www.ultradns.net/index.php?fuseaction=order

Comment: @sopppas: You really ought to look at the "additional queries" and query counts per month.  5,000 seems low, unless it's a small, relatively unused site.

Answer (score 0):

Just considering these DNS services for our online [address book](http://wikiworldbook.com/) application. Our current "free" DNS provider who we bought the domain names through seems to have let us down terribly. We've been trying to crack intermittent slowdowns on our site for several months and it looks as though part or all of the problem has been in the DNS resolution.

Currently considering UltraDNS but they are on the expensive side - especially if you get the overage pricing wrong. Also trying to work out just how many DNS queries you get per visitor or page view - but it looks more complex than that. All we want is fast reliable service as cheaply as possible - but it absolutely has to be fast and reliable. Anyone any experience of how fast DNS Made Easy is and, as a secondary question, whether their name server facilities are in the USA?